# Build ami of hardened coreos from terraform

Tags: terraform

I'm creating a terraform script to deploy an environment of kubernetes and coreos, is there a way to not use the existing ones of coreos and create my own hardened version of coreos?

aws_ami_from_instance does not work for me, since I must have a base instance.

Comment: You use Packer for this before Terraform: https://www.packer.io/

Comment: @MattSchuchard thank you! i think this is my solution.